# How to construct a basis topology with an atlas

Tags: general-topology, geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a set and $\mathcal A$ be an atlas in $M$. It is easy to show that:
$$\big\{O\subseteq M: \varphi(O\cap \mathcal U) \textrm{ is open in }\mathbb R^n\textrm{ for each } (\mathcal U,\varphi)\in \mathcal A\big\}$$
is a topology in $M$ that makes each $\varphi:\mathcal U\to \varphi(\mathcal U)\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ a homeomorfism.

I was asking myself if it is possible to construct a topology in $M$ by finding a basis following the next result:

> Let $\mathcal B$ be a collection of subsets of a set $M$ such that:
>
> 1. For each $x\in X$ there is $B_x\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in B_x$.
> 2. If $B_1,B_2\in\mathcal B$ and $x\in B_1\cap B_2$ then $\exists B_x\in \mathcal B$ such that $x\in B_x\subset B_1\cap B_2.$
>
> Then:
> $$\Big\{\bigcup_{B\in \mathcal B'}B: \mathcal B'\subseteq \mathcal B \Big\}.$$
> is a topology in $x$ with basis $\mathcal B$.

I can't do that without supposing that $\mathcal A$ es a maximal atlas

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a base. It suffices to note that the atlas gives a so-called "fundamental cover" of $M$: a cover by open subsets $O_i, i \in I$ each of which has a topology in a consistent way (in the sense that $O_i \cap O_j$ gets the same topology as a subspace of $O_i$ or $O_j$, every time such an intersection is non-empty).

For such a cover we can define the topology on $M$ as $\{O \subseteq M\mid O \cap O_i \text{ open in } O_i \text{ for all } i \in I\}$ and a function $f: M \to Y$ is continuous iff $f\restriction_{O_i}$ is continuous for all $i$. This is a standard construction.

In your case the atlas gives you an open cover (by definition) and the topology on each member set is fixed by the homeomorphism with $\Bbb R^n$.

IMO this is the most natural way to get the topology of $M$ from the atlas.